# Error when deleting some node

Tags: 7

After pressing the delete button the following message appeared:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

How can I solve this problem?

when deleting field The system log says:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '[name].field_deleted_data_5' doesn't exist: SELECT field_deleted_data_50.entity_type AS entity_type, field_deleted_data_50.entity_id AS entity_id, field_deleted_data_50.revision_id AS revision_id, field_deleted_data_50.bundle AS bundle FROM {field_deleted_data_5} field_deleted_data_50 WHERE (field_deleted_data_50.deleted = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (field_deleted_data_50.bundle = :db_condition_placeholder_1) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => patient_info ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_query() (line 577 of C:\xampp\htdocs[name]\modules\field\modules\field_sql_storage\field_sql_storage.module

Comment: are you close error message try to open error message to know the error

Comment: no just when delete some node it's show up

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Have you deleted any tables in the database? Perhaps some with names beginning with `field_deleted_data_`?

Comment: i already deleted some tables fields, maybe yes i deleted.
can i just import this table from fresh drupal 7 engine ?

Comment: Maybe you could restore the missing tables from your last db backup? I wonder why there is field_deleted_data_5 only once and field_deleted_data_50 in all other cases. Maybe there is a typo in the field_sql_storage.module line 577 ?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your problem is that you have delete a field on your node, which makes Drupal rename the table storing the field data to `field_deleted_data_ID`. The error you are getting is that one of such tables is missing, and the delete fails since the query to delete the data creates a SQL error.

I know of two ways to solve this.

- Recreate the table deleted.
- Delete the field info from `field_config` and possibly `field_config_instance`.

Comment: I'm running into this problem months after the delete happened without knowing the details around that delete event. Any sense what the sql would be to recreate the table? It seems this would work, but what IS a working structure that could make Drupal happy again. Regarding deleting the field info from those two tables...how would you figure out which field?

Comment: @greggles deleted fields have deleted = 1 in field_config

Comment: So, interestingly enough I have records in field_config and field_config_instance that both look like partially deleted data. BUT...the field_names in one don't match the field_names in the other. Is that somewhat to be expected? Thanks for your help!